# Code Coverage of a dll file

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I have a `.exe` file which loads a `.dll` file dynamically. The `.dll` file is passed as an argument to the program.  Can I get code coverage of the `.dll` file using any coverage tools? What tools can I use and how to use them?

Comment: Is the DLL a .NET one?

Comment: No, the DLL is implemented in C++, so its a win32/Com DLL.

Comment: Do you have the source code?

Comment: Yes, I have the source code for DLL file, but not for .exe file.

Comment: I've tagged your question for a specific audience - there are plenty of c++ tools about and many discussed on stack overflow but as I haven't used any I am not going to answer by just posting links to these tools - hopefully someone who has used these tools and can recommend will respond.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO (ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) but try out [opencppcoverage](https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/) which worked perfectly in my dll case.

Comment: Shaun Wilde thanks. Martin I tried OpenCppCoverage and it doesn't recognise the DLL file that is taken as an argument to the program.

Comment: You need to start the program that uses the DLL with opencppcoverage and provide filters to only display your files, at least that how it worked for me.